# What are useful Command-line Commands on Mac OS X?

Tags: command-line-interface, mac, mac-osx-server, osx-leopard

Per the [Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/3780/useful-commandline-commands-on-windows) and [Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/6269/useful-commandline-commands-on-linux) threads, what commands do you find most useful in [Mac OS X Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Server) (or Client)?

Comment: agreed, this site seems to be far more negative that stackoverflow, people seem poised to 'down' any post they don't think meets their standards - it's enough to make me walk away.

Comment: thx, chopper3. maybe it was voted down for being mac related. i can understand not wanting to see a lot of apple stuff, but really just add /ignore "mac" to your tags, and it's sorted

Comment: there's loads of apple specific stuff on this site, people here just seem to enjoy being negative.

Comment: to be expected i suppose... we are sysadmins :-)

Comment: I like your username...username :)

Comment: sysadmins spend more time with end users and tend to be more negative than programmers. ymmv.

Comment: I generally dislike these kinds of questions for being (at least in my mind) attempts to gain rep points. Not to say that I don't find it useful (hence my +1), but I prefer to see questions that are trying to solve problems.

Comment: @gWaldo get off the fence and just vote the question down already. i'll get over it, and my honor will be intact ;)

Answer (score 28):

```
say "some text"
```

Famously used for [getting people back into their apartments](http://xkcd.com/530/), `say` takes your arguments and reads them aloud through the audio output device.

Comment: And it speaks very well -- see http://www.macosxhints.com/comment.php?mode=view&cid=107211 for a list of phrases such as *My name is Dr. Smith and I live on Smith Dr.*, *The soldier decided to desert his dessert in the desert* and *Since there is no time like the present, he thought it was time to present the present* :-)

Answer (score 23):

`pbpaste` and `pbcopy` to interact with the pasteboard (aka clipboard).

Examples:

```
# copies the directory listing
ls -l | pbcopy

# get pasteboard lines containing foo and save them in a_file
pbpaste | grep foo > a_file
```

I think they default to using the macroman encoding, so if you want UTF-8 (which you do) you should check out these links:

- http://sigpipe.macromates.com/2005/10/11/clipboard-access-from-shell-utf-8/
- http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20081231012753422&query=pbpaste

Answer (score 19):

```
fs_usage
```

Lets you monitor file system activity. Handy if you want to see what files some app creates. See http://rentzsch.com/macosx/fs_usageIntro for more explanation.

Comment: Now that Rentzsch has moved his blog to Tumblr without re-publishing his archives, one can read his explanation of this great tool here: http://web.archive.org/web/20091231090628/http://rentzsch.com/macosx/fs_usageIntro

Comment: Also worth reading: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?FsUsageTips

Answer (score 17):

```
open .
```

Opens a finder window in the current working directory.

Comment: for launching other apps, use something like: open -a "activity monitor"

Comment: Freunde schöner Götterfunke...I mean, thank you, thank you, thank you!! I was looking for a Windows like "start ." and this is it!

Comment: 'open filename' acts the same as double-clicking on a file in the Finder -- it'll launch the associated application and open the file.

Answer (score 13):

From the command line, I like having the ability to:

Create and burn a "universal" CD/DVD:

```
$ mkisofs -allow-multidot -allow-leading-dots -d -hide-rr-moved \
-l -joliet-long -R -T -v \
-V VOLUME_NAME -o output.iso root-cd-dir/
$ hdiutil burn -noverifyburn output.iso
```

Create an ISO image from a CD/DVD:

```
$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2s0
$ dd if=/dev/disk2s0 of=cdname.iso bs=32m
```

Being able to forget the otool command when I'm seeking ldd:

```
$ alias ldd='printf "Sending command to \'\''otool -L\'\'' --\n" && otool -L'
```

Mount a disk image from the command line:

```
$ hdid diskimage.dmg (or .iso)
```

Use preview to access a man page:

```
$ man -t rsync | open -f -a /Applications/Preview.app
```

Comment: +1 for the manpage / Preview hint. Awesome.

Answer (score 12):

The 'airport' CLI utility is my favorite. See http://osxdaily.com/2007/01/18/airport-the-little-known-command-line-wireless-utility/. It will show you details like the signal level, noise level, and the BSSID of the AP you're associated to.

Comment: Cool. Eg:

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -I

Shows you detailed information on signal quality, noise, security, and other WiFi network attributes.

Answer (score 11):

```
ipconfig getpacket en0
```

Displays network configuration for the primary Ethernet interface (en0).

If you're used to Windows and think "ipconfig" is broken - it's not ;-) You just need to add a couple arguments

Comment: Of course, if you're used to Linux, 'ifconfig en0' works just as well.

Comment: Or use `en1` if you're on wireless.

Answer (score 11):

```
drutil tray open
```

Invaluable (over ssh) when there's no keyboard connected since the eject button on Apple optical drives isn't accessible from outside the case.

Answer (score 11):

It can't be said enough, "open" is great. You can open documents in their GUI program and you can select the GUI program with -a as well. For example,

```
open -a vlc movie.avi
```

will open VLC and tell it to load movie.avi in your current dir.

```
open movie.avi
```

would open it with whatever program is the default. If you just want to open a program, you can do that too:

```
open -a system\ preferences
```

will run System Preferences. You can open Urls too:

```
open vnc://myserver:5900
```

will open Screen Sharing and connect to myserver.

Check out

```
man open
```

to see all flags you can use.

Answer (score 10):

```
softwareupdate
```

Update your mac from the CLI.

Answer (score 9):

```
networksetup
```

Configure everything you find in the Network Preference Pane in System Preferences on the command line. Makes writing scripts, or doing things remotely *much* easier.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo changeip -checkhostname
```

Checks that forward and reverse DNS resolution are healthy, and often shows you the command you can use to fix the problem. If it says "the names match, there is nothing to change" you're in good shape. Vital if you ever change your server's network configuration. Also important to use this before you promote your server to an Open Directory Master.

Answer (score 8):

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

I find myself using that one heaps to flush the DNS cache, on 10.5+.

Comment: Of note, this only works in Mac OS X 10.5

Comment: I just checked, it also works on 10.6.

Comment: Upvoted as I find myself having to run this more often than not, however don't remember having to flush the Linux or Windows DNS cache. Perhaps OS X is particularly aggressive at DNS caching?

Answer (score 7):

```
ping 224.0.0.1
```

Ping *all* devices on your subnet

Answer (score 7):

The **Command-Line Administration** guide put out by Apple is invaluable.

Googling for ["command line administration mac"](http://www.google.com/search?q=command+line+administration+mac) gives good results.

Command-Line Administration for Mac OS X [10.5](http://images.apple.com/server/macosx/docs/Command_Line_Admin_v10.5.pdf), [10.4](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/Command_Line_v10.4.pdf), and [10.3](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/MacOSXSrvr10.3_CommandLineAdminGuide.pdf).

Other useful guides are at http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/resources/.

Answer (score 7):

```
last
```

shows who has logged into a system, how long they used it, and when the system has been restarted.

Here is a sample of the output:

```
clinton   ttys000                   Thu May 28 22:33   still logged in
clinton   console                   Thu May 28 08:05   still logged in
reboot    ~                         Thu May 28 08:05 
shutdown  ~                         Wed May 27 20:15 
clinton   console                   Wed May 27 17:33 - 20:15  (02:42)
...

wtmp begins Thu May 14 09:26
```

Answer (score 7):

```
srm
```

Command line version for secure delete.

Answer (score 7):

```
 lsof
```

*list open files*

Handy when you want to eject your USB drive and are told that it is in use and to please quit all applications and try again.

```
$ sudo lsof /Volumes/CLINTON
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    55966 clinton  cwd    DIR  14,12    16384    2 /Volumes/CLINTON
lsof    56042    root  cwd    DIR  14,12    16384    2 /Volumes/CLINTON
lsof    56043    root  cwd    DIR  14,12    16384    2 /Volumes/CLINTON
```

In this instance, I had `cd`ed onto the drive and so bash was accessing the volume.

Note that if you see 'mds' entries, it means that spotlight is indexing the drive.

Answer (score 6):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "AppName" to quit'
```

Lets you quit an application from the shell.

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep'
```

Useful last line of a long shell script, puts Mac to sleep when script is done. I have it aliased to iSleep.

```
pbpaste | script.sh |pbcopy
```

takes contents of pasteboard (edit->copy) and pipes it to script.sh. The results are put onto the pasteboard for you to edit->paste into a document.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.commandlinefu.com

While not specifically a Mac resource, it is using the icon for the Terminal, and most of the list of really useful commands will work.

Answer (score 5):

```
sw_vers
```

Displays the currently installed version and build of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5):

```
mcxquery
```

this will let you see what sort of MCX (Managed Client) settings are being applied to a client machine.

[The GUI equivalent is to go to System Profiler, and, under the Software section, click on "Managed Client".]

It is useful to determine if a machine is managed and to see if it is getting the settings you expect.

Answer (score 4):

```
system_profiler
```

Give you the same results as you get when you choose About This Mac -> More Info, only on the command line.

Running

```
system_profiler -usage
```

or looking at the man page will give you tips on how to use it.

A couple of examples:

```
system_profiler -xml > MySystem.spx
# and later,
open MySystem.spx  # or just double click on it in the Finder
```

this will dump the system profile to a file which can be looked at later on a different machine.

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

Tells you about all your USB devices (including their Vendor and Product IDs, which can aid in tracking down drivers).

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep "Product ID" -c
```

will tell you how many USB devices are plugged in (including internal USB devices), which is useful to see if the computer sees a device (or, if, say, Parallel's grabbed it or it is dead.)  [Do note that in the System Profiler GUI App, you can choose View -> Refresh from the menu to update the list; that may just be easier.]

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType
```

will get you basic hardware info (useful for asset tracking), and

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep Serial
```

will give you the machine's serial number.

Answer (score 4):

```
ifconfig en0 ether 00:00:00:00:00:00
```

Changes (spoofs) MAC address until next reboot

Comment: I came across this a few days ago here: http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/mac-os-x-spoofing-mac-addresses-in-5-seconds/ - handy for testing your DHCP service settings

Answer (score 4):

```
df -h
```

To check how many disk space I currently have on all the disk.

Answer (score 4):

```
dns-sd -B _ssh
dns-sd -B _rfb
dns-sd -B _services._dns-sd._udp
```

List servers advertising in Bonjour. The last suggestion lists the types of service that you can list. The listing is live, hit Ctrl-C when you've seen enough.

The same command comes in recent Linuxes and in the Bonjour SDK for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

```
opendiff file1 file2
```

Runs [FileMerge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Developer_Tools#FileMerge) (a graphical `diff` that comes with Apple Developer Tools) on `file1` and `file2`.

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo opensnoop
```

in Leopard and newer, reports which processes open files, whether successfully or not.  You can ask it to look at all files being opened across the system, by a specific process, or if any process is opening a given file, with different sorts of timestamps, and to show if errors occur.

Here are some more details:

- [opensnoop (Mac file open watcher)](http://aplawrence.com/MacOSX/opensnoop.html)
- [Hidden Gems In Leopard: OpenSnoop](http://gigaom.com/apple/hidden-gems-in-leopard-opensnoop/)

opensnoop is a [dtrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace) script; there are many others in /usr/bin that look at things like which system calls a process is making, what processes it is creating and what I/O it is doing.  Run `apropos DTrace` for a list, and look at man pages for details.

---

I found out about opensnoop when struggling to diagnose why a Comic Life Magiq 1.1 was crashing on OS 10.5.8 for users with network accounts.

I ran (several times, on different accounts, via ssh):

```
sudo opensnoop -e -n Comic > output.txt
```

The last file opened by network users was something like this (with a full path):

```
/Network/Servers/.../username/Library/Icons/WebpageIcons.db
```

which reminded me that Safari 5.0 was crashing for network users, and we worked around it by either managing a preference to not cache favicons or by redirecting a file.  Apple apparently fixed the issue in Safari 5.0.1, and when I upgraded to Safari 5.0.2 yesterday, it fixed the crash for Comic Life Magiq users.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -restart -agent
```

Starts the Remote Desktop service (useful if you only have SSH access but want to do something using the GUI on your client Mac). For more options, see: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2370

Answer (score 3):

```
drutil eject
```

will eject a CD.

Answer (score 3):

Truly Mac only:
I saw 'open .' above, but open will open any document or app you pass to it.

Generic Unix that I use the most:
sudo is pretty handy for changing system config files, etc, which I actually edit in vi.

kill can't be overstated when something hangs (or when another user is still logged into my desktop in the background and I want to log them out, nasty I know but it's *my* desktop)

ssh/scp - I love that in OSX I can just open a terminal and connect to any of our servers. That alone made me happy to drop Windows.

ifconfig/ping/whois/nmap etc

Comment: Well, `open` is not so truly Mac only... On Windows this command is named `start` (based on the file extension for files, though internet addresses are supported as well).

Comment: `gnome-open` is Gnome's analogous command for this.

Comment: I believe you should usually use `xdg-open` rather than `gnome-open` because it's portable to other desktop environments (XFCE, KDE, etc).

Answer (score 3):

```
lsof -i
```

lists Internet ports that are open.  Sample output:

```
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
SystemUIS   223 clinton   11u  IPv4 0x3e21b08      0t0  UDP *:*
ARDAgent    262 clinton   16u  IPv4 0x3e21be0      0t0  UDP *:net-assistant
ARDAgent    262 clinton   18u  IPv4 0x5f01a68      0t0  TCP *:net-assistant (LISTEN)
AppleVNCS   263 clinton    4u  IPv6 0x3e274bc      0t0  TCP *:vnc-server (LISTEN)
Opera     48365 clinton   20u  IPv4 0x5f01e64      0t0  TCP WTD-Staff-BlackmoreC:57094->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
Opera     48365 clinton   23u  IPv4 0x5b12a68      0t0  TCP WTD-Staff-BlackmoreC:57095->stackoverflow.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
```

Use `sudo` if you want the ports open by all users, and the flags `-n` and `-P` will disable name resolution and port names and give you numbers instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know what sort of line endings a file has, just run

```
file /path/to/your-file
```

ex:

```
$ file imports/sample-students.txt 
imports/sample-students.txt: ASCII text, with CR line terminators
```

Answer (score 3):

`scutil --dns`

Will display the order for DNS resolution. Useful for when you're creating or debugging your Network settings.

Answer (score 2):

```
ifconfig | grep cast
```

is great for getting your IP address, and

```
ifconfig en1 | grep eth
```

works well for getting a MAC address.  Using en1 will (almost always) get the Airport's MAC address, which is handy if only known devices are allowed onto your wireless network.  Conversely, if you use en0 -- the built-in ethernet port -- you can then look the machine up in your Open Directory, like so:

```
ldapsearch -x -h odm -b "cn=computers,dc=odm,dc=pretendoco,dc=com" "macAddress=00:0d:93:b5:82:88"
```

(Assuming your server was 'odm' and the realm is ODM.PRETENDCO.COM).

Answer (score 2):

ipconfig is sometimes useful:

Getting current IP address on interface:

```
$ ipconfig getifaddr en1
10.110.2.25
```

Getting the DHCP information that was last received:

```
$ ipconfig getpacket en1
op = BOOTREPLY
htype = 1
flags = 0
hlen = 6
hops = 0
xid = 143857879
secs = 0
ciaddr = 0.0.0.0
yiaddr = 10.110.2.25
siaddr = 0.0.0.0
giaddr = 0.0.0.0
chaddr = 00:aa:bb:cc:dd:ee
sname = 
file = 
options:
Options count is 7
dhcp_message_type (uint8): ACK 0x5
server_identifier (ip): 1.1.1.1
lease_time (uint32): 0xe10
router (ip_mult): {10.110.0.1}
domain_name_server (ip_mult): {1.1.1.1, 1.1.1.2}
subnet_mask (ip): 255.255.252.0
end (none):
```

Answer (score 2):

This question overlaps quite a bit with [this one about tools a UNIX administrator cannot live without](https://serverfault.com/questions/3478/tools-a-unix-administrator-cannot-live-without).  Many of the command-line tools for Mac OS X have UNIX roots, such as `df`, `du`, and `which`; however there are notable exceptions that have no obvious UNIX equivalents, such as `osascript`, `open`, `pbcopy`, `pbpaste`, and `say`.

Answer (score 2):

How to enable Time Machine to backup to a NAS.

```
defaults write com.apple.systempreferences TMShowUnsupportedNetworkVolumes 1
```

Find MAC address

```
ifconfig en0 | grep ether | sed s/://g | sed s/ether//
```

Command to create sparsebundle to copy over to NAS

```
sudo hdiutil create -nospotlight -library SPUD -size 160g -fs "Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+" -type SPARSEBUNDLE -volname "<VOLNAME>" ./<HOSTNAME>_<MAC_ADDRESS>.sparsebundle
```

Works like charm backing up to my ReadyNAS.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the usual Unix suspects I find the following useful :-

- dsconfigad - Edits the Active Directory settings and binds a computer
- defaults - Edit preferences
- plutil - Converts [plist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list) to and from text
- softwareupdate - run Software Update from the command-line
- installer - install packages from the command-line
- networksetup - set and get various things such as the computer name

If you master those and the usual Unix stuff you have all you need for Mac administration from the command-line.

Answer (score 2):

It is a freeware third-party tool, but

```
edit
```

is really handy.  It is a command-line tool that you can optionally install the first time you run [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/TextWrangler/).  [Other text editors (BBEdit, TextMate) likely provide something analogous.]

```
edit path/to/somefile
```

Opens up the file in TextWrangler, and will let you authenticate if you don't normally have permission to edit it.  (You can even do it from an ssh session, and it'll open it for the logged-in graphical user).

Better still is that you can pipe things to it.

```
lsof -i | edit
```

for example, will show you your open network connections and open them up in TextWrangler, where you can search (and scroll) through them easily.

Comment: There is a similar Textmate version called "mate" which is installed with the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Gain a **root shell without enabling the root user** (as Apple itself requires sometimes in their docs in order to do some "geeky" stuff, ie to set system-wide language)

```
sudo bash
```

This gives you a root shell where you can do everything you want as root, without having to prepend every command with the sudo command.

This may be dangerous, but we are sysadmins, we know what we are doing, don't we? :)

Comment: I prefer "sudo -s", it's shorter and I think it may do some specific processing to start the shell "properly".

Comment: Yes, but I prefer explicitly run bash for more than a reason:  
- may be there is no env $SHELL defined  
- may be $SHELL or /etc/password define a different shell (sh, ksh, etc)  
- I don't think "-s" would do any magic in running the shell "properly"

But you are right, this is an alternative. +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

`killall -9 appname` force quits an app. Pretty useful if you can't get into Activity Monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that there's a nifty bash construct that you can use instead of the seq command missing in Mac OS:

```
echo { 18..21 }
```

Comment: OSX has the BSD-derived `jot` utility that romps all over `seq`. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

A bit pedestrian for this audience, no doubt, but I use:

screencapture -i -c

to grab whatever I want from the screen It's really handy and does things that Grab won't allow me to grab.

Answer (score 1):

```
sqlite3 foo.db
```

Starts an interactive [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) session.  If foo.db does not exist, it will be created.

Answer (score 1):

du -d 1 -h

Displays disk usage statistics for the current directory in human readable form.

man [command]

One of the most used commands. Tells you how to use everything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo slapconfig -destroyldapserver
```

Force Demote an LDAP Replica to Standalone. If your Open Directory Master is misconfigured, sometimes trying to demote an Open Directory Replica using Server Admin will fail (eg: you might find your Replica server refuses to demote). You can use slapconfig to force it to demote on these occasions.

Answer (score 1):

```
 which program
```

searched the path for program, and tells you which executable is invoked if you run program without specifying a full path.

It is usually most useful as a shorthand for typing a path.

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ ls -l `which python`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  72 30 Jan 22:56 /usr/bin/python -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python
```

Comment: "type -a foo" will show you all programs named foo, and works for all Bourne shells.

Comment: `type` will also include aliases and functions

Answer (score 1):

These are basic, but handy if you have amnesia:

Who am I?

```
id
```

Where am I standing?

```
pwd
```

What building am I?

```
hostname
```

What's its address?

```
ifconfig |grep inet
```

Answer (score 1):

OS X specific things I haven't seen mentioned:

`mdfind` uses the Spotlight search indexes from the commandline, so you can do full-text searches without using the Search pulldown.

`networksetup -` will show you all the crazy syntax it supports; this is the commandline equivalent of the Network preference pane.

`sudo launchctl list` - shows the running launchctl jobs. remember `launchctl stop X.XX.X` will just 'stop' (kill) the currently running instance of a persistent process; to really make it stop running use `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/X.XX.X.plist`.

Answer (score 1):

What DHCP licenses does the client hold?

```
sudo ls -lt /private/var/db/dhcpclient/leases
```

List the firewall allow/denies:

```
sudo ipfw list
```

Generate a high-entropy password (double click on a promising 16 character string to copy/paste):

```
head -c90 /dev/random | uuencode -m pwd | hexdump -C
```

Answer (score 1):

Ever wanted to know what the IP address of another Mac that you can see is in the Finder is on your LAN thanks to Bonjour?

```
dscacheutil -q host -a name OtherMac.local
```

dscacheutil is surprisingly useful and versatile. You can do a lot more with it than just flush the DNS cache (as mentioned elsewhere here), i.e. user lookups and cache stats and dumps.

Answer (score 0):

```
locate "foo"
```

Displays any file on your system with "foo" in its filename. I must use this almost as often as I use Spotlight.

Comment: mdfind will query spotlight from the command line.  See http://www.tuaw.com/2008/01/04/a-slightly-simpler-command-line-spotlight-search/

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo reboot
```

reboots the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most "useful" command but `say` is pretty fun.

For example `say I love serverfault` to have it read back what you type after "say."