# Suggestions for Terminal Emulators on Linux, Windows and Mac

Tags: mac-osx, terminal, cross-platform, emulator

I've recently found the [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/terminator/) terminal emulator for Gnome. I really like this

There is a [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) written in Java.

For windows it is lightyears ahead of the installed rxvt.

However, I have found that it suffers the same limitations as iConsole, namely with keybindings.

Has anyone suggestions for Terminal emulators on the Mac?

Comment: I had a look at the Java version of Terminator but the Java Terminator for Windows "Requires Cygwin and Cygwin Ruby" so isn't as useful as it might have been.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is the obvious choice.  It's lightweight but has all the functionality I've ever needed.

[There are ports of PuTTY to various Operating Systems](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/links.html) including various mobile phone versions.  There is a [Mac port of PuTTY](http://putty.darwinports.com/) but I've never used it.

Answer (score 3):

[I use ZOC](http://www.emtec.com/zoc/index.html) for work on remote servers SSH/Telnet and programming routers directly (null modem cable) on both Windows and Mac.  Locally I'm mostly too lazy to start it up and instead just open a Terminal.app

Answer (score 1):

I like [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net) as a free replacement for the standard Apple Terminal.app. Particularly for the bookmarks feature that the standard Apple offering lacks.
Keybindings are also configurable...

Answer (score 1):

[MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net)
is a terminal for Windows, with an X server and a set of Unix commands (GNU/Cygwin) packaged in a single portable exe file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good writeup on a few alternatives [here](http://muffinresearch.co.uk/archives/2006/05/23/alternatives-to-terminalapp-on-mac-osx/)

Personally I have never found much of a need to seek a replacement for the built-in terminal.app

Comment: That writeup is from 2006.

Answer (score 0):

I always hated PuTTY.

I used to buy SecureCRT, but now I use the Mac terminal client mostly. For linux, I generally use the default, but most of the work that I do is on my MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

I used iTerm under Tiger, and was pleased that Terminal had been enhanced for Leopard.  It wasn't quite good enough, but I found that with some tweaking, Terminal is pretty good.  [This echoes [my answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/10125/how-to-setup-the-mac-os-x-terminal-so-its-just-peachy/13931#13931) to the [How to setup the Mac OS X Terminal so it’s *just peachy*?](https://serverfault.com/questions/10125/how-to-setup-the-mac-os-x-terminal-so-its-just-peachy)]

**Here is what I did to tweak Terminal to my liking:**

Install [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) so that the application can be extended, with things like:

- [TerminalColors](http://www.culater.net/software/TerminalColors/TerminalColors.php) allows you to change the the standard text colours (so, for example, a colorized `ls` output won't look awful)
- [Tab Namer](http://ericanderson.us/2008/03/02/terminalapp-tab-namer-v01-alpha/) let you name your tabs.
- [Terminal Tab Switcher](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/12/10/tab-switching-in-terminal) let you use hotkeys to switch between tabs (instead of windows).
- [Visor](http://docs.blacktree.com/visor/visor), makes terminal drop down (like the Quake console) at the push of a key combo.

Then, install some nice mono-spaced [programmer fonts](http://keithdevens.com/wiki/ProgrammerFonts).  I like [Droid Sans Mono](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-sans-mono-great-coding-font), [Envy Code R](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/12/26/Envy-Code-R-programming-font--preview-available-for-download), and [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html).  Set up a nice theme.  ([IR_Black](http://blog.infinitered.com/entries/show/6) is a nice one to download.)

Lastly, and not really relevant to which terminal emulator you are using, the [`open`](https://serverfault.com/questions/7346/useful-commandline-commands-on-mac-os/7468#7468) command is really nice when working on the Mac in conjunction with the GUI.  `open .` opens the current directory in the finder, and `open filename` opens the file as though you'd double-clicked on it in the Finder.   [`pbcopy` and `pbpaste`](https://serverfault.com/questions/7346/useful-commandline-commands-on-mac-os/10152#10152) are handy, too.

Answer (score 0):

I usually Stick with putty, but for a while I was using [Ponderosa](http://en.poderosa.org/). Its written in .NET.

It has a tabbed interfaces, and offers serial connections. You can even invoke a local cygwin shell.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu Linux all the time and I've never found a problem with the built in gnome terminal.

Answer (score 0):

On linux my favourite is KDE3's "Konsole", the KDE4 version is OK, but not quite as good.

I've found gnome-terminal to be near unusable for serious work due to stupid keybindings.