# How to setup the Mac OS X Terminal so it's *just peachy*?

Tags: mac-osx, mac, terminal

My Terminal is awesome, has every detail just right (for me anyway), and now I'm setting up a few new macs around here and I have no idea whatsoever how to get their terminals to a pretty state. My user account is rather old, has been migrated over many OS X releases and machines, so my Terminal setup has grown rather organically over the years.

What I need is a recipe to start from scratch, so 1) I know what I've done, and 2) I can reproduce it anywhere.

Things I'm looking for:

- Full UTF8 support. Setting `LC_*`, displaying characters correctly, accepting input… I hear this got much easier in 10.5, maybe it all works out of the box now?
- Setup of OS X-style keyboard text navigation (option-arrows, etc)
- How you particularly handle meta-key support? (other than `ESC`'ing your way around)
- Other things to help our n00bs get around in the shell, such as:

  - List of useful default key bindings (`^A`, `^D`, etc…)
  - Mac-specific `.profile`, `.inputrc` goodness
  - Mac-specific tools such as `pbpaste` & `pbcopy`, Open Terminal Here, etc
- If at all possible, a list of files to copy over to another machine that encompasses all the changes made to tune the Terminal. (dotrc files, plists, etc)
- And, well, anything else really. Just keep the scope on the Mac OS X Terminal application, rather than general unix setup and tools.

---

**I think a collection of incomplete answers would be a good start. Post one or two things you remember having done, we'll vote them up, and after a few days I'll try to compile it all into a summary answer.**

Comment: From your requirements, you've already gone beyond "keep the scope on the Mac OS X Terminal application", since you're talking about bash configuration as well.

Comment: Only is the context that it's required to make the Terminal work correctly, accept custom input sequences you set up in its preferences, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Do nothing. Stick with the default unless there is a valid reason not to.

I see you mention setting up a new unix developer on a Mac. If this developer has any Mac experience, he'll be used to the default and will probably get confused if you've customized things. If you're writing software that ships out to customers, the customer will (usually) have the default configuration and so trying to debug on a system that is "unfamiliar" (i.e. not your comfy customized environment) can be *very* frustrating.

If (like me) you work with many different machines and operating systems you quickly learn the defaults for that system, what keyboard shortcuts are portable between systems, standard commands for each OS, etc.

What you really need to do here is get a new machine, see what *doesn't* work (looks like UTF-8 support is fine, I just checked on my Mac) and see if there are any valid reasons for making changes. Developers have their own preferences when it comes to the command line and really don't appreciate being forced into using what someone else thinks is an "ideal setup". It might be ideal for you, but Apple are pretty damn good at figuring out sensible defaults.

The only thing I'd really change by default when setting up a new Mac, is making the Tab key cycle through all controls (including buttons) rather than just text boxes and lists. I know it's not terminal-related, but it does make a huge difference for us keyboard junkies who rarely lift their hand to use a mouse :)

**Keyboard & Mouse > Keyboard Shortcuts > Full keyboard access > All Controls**

Comment: yea I enable full kdb access too. So, in general I agree with your point, esp. each developer hating others' defaults. But the things I change about the terminal are just to make it more mac-like/mac-friendly, and the other part of the question is just about listing things that are good to know on the mac.

Answer (score 4):

For your Terminal window settings just copy `com.apple.Terminal.plist` from your Preferences folder. That's everything specific to Mac OS X Terminal's application. Everything else is tweaking your shell, and it's settings so what you're asking for isn't easily done - it'd be much easier to add features as they are missing and documenting as you migrate from one computer to another.

However, for specific preferences spread across the different UNIX utilities is different for each one. If you wanted a blanket that will get the majority of settings you could conceivably just copy any file or folder that starts with a `.` in your home directory but it's far from ideal.

On a side note `pbpaste/pbcopy` are both system utilities so they don't need to be copied, [Open Terminal Here](http://www.entropy.ch/software/applescript/) is an AppleScript application.

Comment: Yea, pb* is just a thing to put on a list to tell people "hey it's good, use it". I'm trying to compile everything to setup a new unix developer on a mac.

Comment: You might want to heavily re-word the question then... the question as it stands lacks much direction or purpose. At first it's asking about Terminal.app and then it's asking about other utilities. Edit it so it states what you're actually trying to do rather than the pieces.

Answer (score 2):

> List of useful default key bindings (^A, ^D, etc…)

I just noticed that the Mac OS X Terminal accepts both control and meta (esc) Emacs keystrokes for navigation.  Here is a partial list:

```
C-a  Move the cursor to the start of the line
C-e  Move the cursor to the end of the line
C-f  Move the cursor forward one character
C-b  Move the cursor backwards one character
M-f  Move the cursor forward one word
M-b  Move the cursor backwards one word
C-d  Delete the current character
M-d  Delete to the end of the word
```

Comment: It's not really the _terminal_ but the shell that accepts Emacs-style input. Bash can take Emacs or Vi bindings, and Emacs is the default. To see the difference, try `set -o vi`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't advise doing this for other people, and none of these reference your specific questions, but here is what I did to tweak Terminal to my liking:

- The following require the use of [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) so that can extend the application:

  - [TerminalColors](http://www.culater.net/software/TerminalColors/TerminalColors.php) allows you to change the the standard text colours (so, for example, a colorized `ls` output won't look awful)
  - [Tab Namer](http://ericanderson.us/2008/03/02/terminalapp-tab-namer-v01-alpha/) let you name your tabs.
  - [Terminal Tab Switcher](http://ciaranwal.sh/2007/12/10/tab-switching-in-terminal) let you use hotkeys to switch between tabs (instead of windows).
  - [Visor](http://docs.blacktree.com/visor/visor), makes terminal drop down (like the Quake console) at the push of a key combo.

Then you may want to set up a few themes.  The [IR_Black](http://blog.infinitered.com/entries/show/6) theme is nice.

Lastly, I'd install some [programmer fonts](http://keithdevens.com/wiki/ProgrammerFonts).  I like [Droid Sans Mono](http://damieng.com/blog/2007/11/14/droid-sans-mono-great-coding-font), [Envy Code R](http://damieng.com/blog/2006/12/26/Envy-Code-R-programming-font--preview-available-for-download), and [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html).

Answer (score 1):

For Mac-specific tools, see: [What are useful Command-line Commands on Mac OS X?](https://serverfault.com/questions/7346/useful-commandline-commands-on-mac-os)

Answer (score 0):

I customize my Terminal.app with a SIMBL plugin that adds the 'copy-on-select' feature. See
http blog.s21g.com/articles/1077 and http github.com/genki/terminalcopyonselect/tree/master .